# How can I clear the formBackingObject after submit?

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there any way to clear my formBackingObject after a submit.

Until now I'm setting every field of a comlex object to null. For example:

```
class Person{
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  // getters and setters
}
```

In my controller I'm doing:

```
  person.setFirstName(null);
  person.setLastName(null);
```

In my system the person class has 10 fields and I don't want to set every single field to null by hand...Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could set it to a new Person, or a default one if you have one.

Or you could use reflection to iterate all the properties and set them to null.